# Flex Air - Get the depth orders of windows (z-index)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Does anybody know if we can get the orders of all opened nativeWindows ?

I would like to compare two nativeWindows, and find which window is above.

Thanks !

Edit :
`NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows` 
return an array of all opened nativeWindows.

But the windows is in the order they were opened. Not in the depth order... For example, if we click on a window, it will take the first place, but its position in this array doesn't change.

Is there another array where the windows would be in this order ? Or another way ton find it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you'll have to create your own Z-Order Manager; perhaps with your own custom Native Window and/or Native Window opener so that you can track when a Window is given focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no native way of doing this. If you need to ensure the correct window is at the top / bottom of the stack based on some condition, you can use the `orderToFront` and `orderToback` methods (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html)).

If your requirements are more complex, you could consider implementing your own system for tracking the depths (re-order your array when any of the order methods are called or the `activate` and `close` events are fired).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes I haven't found anything else. I use a class with an static array and 3 methods (getOrder, setOrder, removeOrder) for manage this order. I placed the listeners on Focus and Close events in my windows custom class.